# Flutter : How to show List of user based in filds?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How to show list of users in FireStore(Firebase Database) Based only in verified Fild !
So if there is non-verified so will not list them in streambuilder, Here my example but I got errors !

```
Widget verified (){
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('verified ',isEqualTo: 'true').getDocuments(),
      builder: (context, data){
       return ListView(
         children: <Widget>[
       Text('${data.data['verified '].toString()}'),
         ],
       );

      },
    );
  }
```

The Error is :

```
Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: []("verified ")
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally use stream builder for firestore u can use like that :

```
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .where('verified ', isEqualTo: 'true')
  .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, data) {
    if (data.hasData) {
      return ListView(
     children: <Widget>[
        Text('${data.data['verified '].toString()}'),
     ],
   );
  }
  return Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
 );
  },
);
```

If u want to use future builder then u have to check for did we got data or not

```
return FutureBuilder(
future: Firestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .where('verified ', isEqualTo: 'true')
    .getDocuments(),
builder: (context, data) {
  if (data.data != null) { //data.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('${data.data['verified '].toString()}'),
      ],
    );
  }
  return CircularProgressIndicator();
},
);
```

Comment: There is an error with the code cus of [] te error is Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: []("verified ")